# Why is the compactified $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,5}$ a stack?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I have question related to the Deligne-Mumford compactification of $\mathcal{M}_{0,5}$ in Chapter V of the book "Counting Surfaces" by Bertrand Eynard, available for free on http://bertrand.eynard.free.fr/book_chap6.pdf. The same example is also worked out in section 5 (page 81) of his lecture notes on compact Riemann surfaces https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06405.pdf.

I'm a string theorist who happens to be very interested in the theory of moduli spaces of Riemann surfaces for several reasons but I'm not a Mathematician who received formal Algebraic Geometry education.

My question is why

\begin{equation}
\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,5} \sim \overline{\mathbb{C}} \times \overline{\mathbb{C}} \cup \mathbb{C} \cup \mathbb{C} \cup \mathbb{C}
\end{equation}

specifically is a stack? Is it because it's an orbifold (with singular points)? If so what is the **finite** automorphism group that acts a stabilizer? Or is it because the boundary is a union of different pieces that have different dimensions? Are the two facts related? What makes it a stack specifically? Why is $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{0,4}}$ for example not a stack? In the book and in the notes, Eynard says it's a complex **manifold**. Is it because after compactification, it simply has the topology of $\mathbb{C}P^1$?

I'm trying to match the different elements of this example to the formal definition of a stack I usually encounter in terms of groupoids, e.g. here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02ZH. In this simple example of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,5}$, what is the coarse moduli space, the fibers, a site $\mathcal{C}$, etc.? I'm trying to use this example to get an intuition into the meaning of an Deligne-Mumford stack.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: OK so something is wrong here. The author claims that $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,5}$ is not a manifold, and he *seems* to be implying that it has irreducible components of different dimensions (i.e. it is not equidimensional). This is FALSE. The spaces $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}$ for $n \geq 3$ are all irreducible and smooth, in fact complex manifolds, and can be regarded as schemes (hence also as stacks, but trivially). Singularities and stacky phenomena only really show up in positive genus...

Comment: I would recommend *An Invitation to Quantum Cohomology* (Koch-Vainsencher) for a down to earth introduction to these moduli spaces. In particular they explain the inductive construction of $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n+1}$ by starting with the smooth variety $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}$, taking the product $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}\times \overline{\mathcal M}_{0,4}\cong \overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n} \times \mathbb P^1$ (also smooth) and then blowing up along certain smooth centers, which directly gives the smoothness of $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. But just to be very clear on my end, are you saying that $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}$ doesn't not even have irreducible components, i.e. codim-1 and codim-2 nodal Riemann surfaces or that it actually has as worked out in the book and notes but it's smooth and therefore not a stack? In other words, to isolate the mistake made by the author, you are saying there are boundaries of different dimensions of the noncompact $\mathcal{M}_{0,n}$ but after compactification, the space $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}$ is still a smooth manifold, hence, not a stack as he claims.

Comment: The loci of nodal Riemann surfaces are closed subsets of positive codimension within the irreducible variety $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}$, i.e. every nodal surface is infinitesimally close to a genuine (smooth) Riemann surface. Again, it's not entirely clear to me what the author is claiming in the first place, so it's hard to isolate the mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll definitely look into the book you suggested above and make sure I understand all the details.